# ¿Porqué Socket.io no recibe mis datos?

Tags: nodejs, socket, socket.io, websocket

Tengo el siguiente script del lado del cliente:

```
var socket = io();
    var from = document.getElementById('nickForm');
    var input = document.getElementById('nickname');

    from.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
        if(input.value){
            socket.emit('new user'), input.value;
        }
    });
```

Y lo siguiente del lado del servidor:

```
    io.on('connection', async socket => {
    socket.on('new user', (data) => {
        console.log('====================================');
        console.log(data);
        console.log('====================================');
        socket.nickname = data;
        users[socket.nickname] = socket;
        updateNicknames();
    });
```

Al ejecutarlo el servidor no recibe el valor del input:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué podría estar haciendo mal? De antemano muchas gracias por la atención brindada.

Comment: Desde mi completa ignorancia: ¿acaso `input.value` no debería estar dentro de la llamada a `socket.emit`? (`socket.emit('new user', input.value);`)

Comment: Estas en toda la razón, muchas gracias, fue algo que no pude ver.